# add slick slider to wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I made HTML/CSS design of a web site, and now I need to convert it to Wordpress. The part that I am working on right now is Adding slick slider to show only on my WP front page. It works perfectly in HTML (because there I incorporated javascript which could be found on actual slick slider website and initiated through 3 div elements with images inside.).

In WP functions.php I added:

```
//Add slider

 add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );

function create_post_type() {
 register_post_type( 'slider',
   array(
   'labels' => array(
    'name' => __( 'Sliders' ),
    'singular_name' => __( 'Slider' ),
    'add_new' => 'Add new slide',
  ),
     'public' => true,

  )
);
}

?>
```

It is supposed to be a custom post type, so with this piece of code, I managed to show Sliders/Add new slider option in WP Dashboard. But now I have no idea what should I do next to make the actual slider show up on my front page. Because when I add a new slide it makes a whole new single image post instead of showing on top of my front page(not header). I am sure there is something else that i am missing, but I have no idea what to do, since this is the first time I had to do something like this. Can anyone help me, please? I am starting to go crazy over this. Thank you so much in advance, everyone.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try the WordPress plugin [Slick Slider](https://wordpress.org/plugins/slick-slider/). It uses native WordPress galleries (in contrast to WP Slick Slider and Image Carousel mentioned in the other answer which uses a custom post type).

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this plugin.

Comment: @fmsthird, unfortunately not. Also see https://wordpress.org/support/topic/compatibility-wp-5-0/

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1 (easiest)
Use the plugin instead: https://nb.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-slick-slider-and-image-carousel/

2 (advanced)
Create a custom loop that fetches all the images from the custom post type and echoes them as a slideshow. Example:

```
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'post_type'              => array( 'slider' ),
);

// The Query
$query_slider = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query_slider->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<div class="your-class">';
    while ( $query_slider->have_posts() ) {
        $query_slider->the_post();
        echo '<div> ';
        the_post_thumbnail();
        echo '</div>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
} else {
    // no posts found
}

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

You also need to enqueue the scripts and stylesheets in the themes functions.php file.

Comment: Thanx a million for a reply! One question - where do I add this code that you wrote? To functions.php as well?

Comment: No. This should be added directly to the template file for the front-page. That should be named either home.php or front-page.php or if you have a custom template for the front page such as template-front-page.php or similar your should add it there.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I just put this in front-page.php (I changed "your-class" to my class name). And before that, I enqueued scripts and styles in funcitons.php. And I still can't see the slider on my page. Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Checklist:
1. Check source and make sure slick.css, slick-theme.css, jQuery and slick/slick.min.js are loaded (in that order) - don´t use the native wordpress jquery - instead use the one referenced in slick slider docs. 
2. Make sure that the images you want to use for the slideshow is set as featured images. One post per slide.
3. Check the front-page source code and look for the html generated by the template. (<div class="your-class">etc...)

Comment: 1. Checked and true. 2. Checked and true. 3. I am not sure what to do with this.  I have html code, but that includes only 3 hard coded images in slider, all wrapped in div element. If I leave it on front page.php, only those three slides are shown, because the page reads that html only. I am going out of my mind. Is there any way I can send you a private email or something, because i would really appreciate your help?

Comment: Sure. Twitterlink in profile - hit me up with a PM and I´ll se what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

I passed a lot of time trying to replicate a complex slide along with slick-lightbox, with not much success.

My best bet was upgrade jquery to version 3 on WordPress and run slick/slick-lightbox out of wordpress.

Console shows no issues, but definitely not for beginners.